# What is the max rate for uploading files in Azure Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, rate-limiting

I created a script to upload some **75000** files to a container in Azure blob storage. But somehow after some **47000** uploads, the auth token failed and it gave auth error due to which all the subsequent requests were canceled.

*For each request, I am checking if the token has failed I am refreshing it and updating it with a new token. That is I am updating tokens with the same refresh token.*

When I tried to investigate rate limits for azure. I found 2 articles.

1. [Scalability and performance targets for standard storage accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/scalability-targets-standard-account?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json)
2. [Throttling Resource Manager requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/request-limits-and-throttling)

One of them says limit to be `20000/sec` while the other says it to be some `10/sec 1200/hr`. Can someone please clarify whats the actual limit is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can someone please clarify whats the actual limit is?

Uploading the objects to an Azure blob storage you should get 20k/s limit.

The limit 1200/h relates to writes if the Resource Manager, it means updating Azure resources, such as creating containers, creating blob storages,...

> auth token failed

When reaching the limit, you suppose to get http 500 or http 503 response (as far I recall, plz check). But you say the `auth token fails` which implies an authentication issue (401, 403 response).  So which is it?  (Btw the auth token has its validity )